# Gerrit with users outside of LDAP

Tags: gerrit

So I am using LDAP for authentication however we have an external developer (customer who contributes to the code) which i wish to give access to the git repos but also the web ui interface. Can this be done without adding them to ldap?

I tried the [create account cmd](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/cmd-create-account.html#_examples) but that does not work.

Is it possible to create a user for web ui that does not use LDAP authentication if you set it as the authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  When you use ldap authentication, all web users must be in ldap.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn Pearce answered the same question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/repo-discuss/eX6bnnhTn8I) on the Gerrit Discussion list and indeed the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a restricted LDAP account and let the developer change his email in gerrit settings. So he will get every notification to his own Inbox.